# Why does standalone not detect the TikZ crop correctly?

Tags: tikz-pgf, margins, standalone

This small example

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xltxtra,textcomp,graphicx,color,tikz}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \clip (0,0) rectangle (12.8cm, 1.15cm);
    \draw (0,0) grid (12.8cm, 1.15cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

generates this output:

[image: output]

Where is the margin / extra space on the left side coming from, and how can I remove it? Shouldn't `\clip` take care of that?

Comment: You don't need `graphicx,color` if you're loading TikZ. You almost certainly shouldn't be loading both `xltxtra` and `textcomp`. That suggests some level of confusion. Do you really want `textpos` for a standalone TikZ picture?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

use

```
\documentclass[
   tikz,
   %border=1pt
]{standalone}
```

With the `tikz` option the `standalone` class knows that it should crop the
environment(s) `tikzpicture` and not only the given text box.

With the border option you can better control the result

Comment: thank you, that worked just fine. Could you maybe elaborate a bit about the use of the tikz option, what does it do?

Comment: see documentation page 7

Comment: This [reference](http://texblog.org/tag/standalone/) shows a *simple* solution: `\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}`.

Comment: @Rubens: `border=...` doesn't solve the problem with the `tikz` key ...

Comment: Alternatively, one could use `multi=tikzpicture,varwidth=false` instead. The only difference according to the documentation is that standalone would *not* load the `tikz` package itself thus one has to do that manually. However, this might help in some situations, e.g., if one uses `\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}` which has to be loaded before `tikz` or else results in `LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.` (which would be impossible if the document class has loaded `tikz` already.

Comment: Pass `svgnames` to the document class itself or use `\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}` everything will be finde.