# Document class standalone and \tikzfading/tikzfadingfrompicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone

## Short Question

Why does

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\begin{document}
    \tikzfading[name=fade right,left color=transparent!0,right color=transparent!100]
    \tikz\fill[red,path fading=fade right](-1,-1)rectangle(1,1);
\end{document}
```

not compile?

---

## The Story

To produce a PDF file with only drawings, one sometimes writes

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
```

so that `standalone` will automatically crop the page regarding Ti*k*Z pictures.

The problem is that a minimal should-work example such as

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\begin{document}
    \tikzfading[name=fade right,left color=transparent!0,right color=transparent!100]
    \tikz\fill[red,path fading=fade right](-1,-1)rectangle(1,1);
\end{document}
```

**does not compile**, while its `article` version

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\begin{document}
    \tikzfading[name=fade right,left color=transparent!0,right color=transparent!100]
    \tikz\fill[red,path fading=fade right](-1,-1)rectangle(1,1);
\end{document}
```

does. And the later gives the desired result.

[image]

This can be solved by putting `\tikzfading` somewhere else. For instance in preamble:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
    \tikzfading[name=fade right,left color=transparent!0,right color=transparent!100]
\begin{document}
    \tikz\fill[red,path fading=fade right](-1,-1)rectangle(1,1);
\end{document}
```

This gives the desired result as well.

[image]

But putting `\tikzfading` in preamble fails if one wants to define the fading locally. To make it really local, one can put it right inside the `tikzpicture`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\begin{document}
    \tikz{
        \tikzfading[name=fade right,left color=transparent!0,right color=transparent!100]
        \fill[red,path fading=fade right](-1,-1)rectangle(1,1);}
\end{document}
```

[image]

We can fix this. Just add a `\pgfresetboundingbox`. Then the weird thing comes: If I set a global `line width`, the doubled line **remains the same width**.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\begin{document}
    \tikz[line width=10]{
        \tikzfading[name=fade right,left color=transparent!0,right color=transparent!100]
        \pgfresetboundingbox
        \fill[red,path fading=fade right](-1,-1)rectangle(1,1);
        \draw[double](-1,-1)--(1,1);
        \draw[      ](-1,1)--(1,-1);}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If anyone is curious, the desired result should be

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
    \tikzfading[name=fade right,left color=transparent!0,right color=transparent!100]
\begin{document}
    \tikz[line width=10]{
        \fill[red,path fading=fade right](-1,-1)rectangle(1,1);
        \draw[double](-1,-1)--(1,1);
        \draw[      ](-1,1)--(1,-1);}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

So far there are two questions, marked in bold above:

- Why does the `standalone` version not compile while the `article` version  does?
- Why does the `\tikzfading` *blocks* the line-width setting for **only** doubled lines?

Comment: You realize the [tikz] argument is not necessary, and removing will solve all your problems.

Comment: @JohnKormylo No I cannot replace `[tikz]` by `\usepackage{tikz}` since it gives **unstable** cropping. (That is what I experienced with other drawings.)

Comment: If you mean the white space on the left, just put a % at the end of the \tikzfading[].  Besides loading the tikz package, [tikz] also sets multi={tikzpicture} and varwidth=false.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I guess it is `multi={tikzpicture}` that dislikes `\tikzfading`. But I need `multi={tikzpicture}` for gathering drawings in one document, in which case I prefer to define fading locally. By the way, there are cases like [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138677/) where `standalone` are not even close. I also had drawn something that gives wider and wider page after compiling multiple times without modifying the code. I cannot recall the content of the drawing so you may ignore this part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Weird, huh?

```
\documentclass[multi={tikzpicture,tikzfading}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\begin{document}
  \tikzfading[name=fade right,left color=transparent!0,right color=transparent!100]%
  \tikz\fill[red,path fading=fade right](-1,-1)rectangle(1,1);
  \endtikzfading
\end{document}
```

---

Here is something which is less confusing and works with other document classes.

```
\documentclass[multi={tikzpicture,wrapper}]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\newenvironment{wrapper}{\parindent=0pt\ignorespaces}{\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapper}
  \tikzfading[name=fade right,left color=transparent!0,right color=transparent!100]%
  \tikz\fill[red,path fading=fade right](-1,-1)rectangle(1,1);
\end{wrapper}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oops, did not see that coming. It seems like we can add anything in `multi=` if it turns out breaking the compiling, right?

Comment: The weird thing is that \endtikzfading is already defined, since tikzfading is not an environment.  But yes, you can add any environment to multi.

Comment: Aha I found it: `\endtikzfading` is defined because we put `multi={tikzfading}`. Standalone defines `\foobar` and `\endfoobar` once there is `multi={foobar}`. But again, why...

Comment: @Symbol1 It's because if you want to keep the contents of multiple environments separately visible but not discarded. But I don't know why you need `tikzfading`. Standalone looks specifically environments. `\tikz` is a very nontrivial macro for `standalone`

Comment: @percusse As far as I know `\tikzfading` is a shortcut for `tikzfadingfrompicture` the environment, just like `\tikz` being a shortcut for `tikzpicture`. Changing to the environment format makes no difference in my case. For instance the first code block: the compiler stops at `\tikzfading`/`tikzfadingfrompicture` and it will never see `\tikz` following.

Comment: I need `tikzfadingfrompicture` because it refers to a PDF feature that is not replaceable by any other command (throughout the TeX world, I guess). I am surprised that `standalone` cannot handle it.

Comment: @Symbol1 Exactly. So it's not an issue on TikZ side. You are expecting standalone to understand the macro was actually an environment which is not. The shortcut does not expand to an environment. Both environment and the shortcut expand to something like a box with a bounding box. Standalone doesn't analyze the output because that's pretty hard.

Comment: @percusse I did not think that much. My concern is that Standalone can handle `\tikzset`, so why cannot it handle `\tikzfading`? I mean... come on... just execute the command as usual... Is that hard?

Comment: @Symbol1 I know what you mean but notice that standalone checks only the things that produces **content** cannot analyze the content itself. `\tikzset` passes this test but the others might not. You can add fading to ignore list of standalone maybe?

Comment: @percusse Sure, as long as the code is pretty short.