# pgfplots + standalone + animate: ! Missing \endgroup inserted.<inserted text>\endgroup\end{tikzpicture} }

Tags: pgfplots, standalone, animate

```
% Doesn't Work
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 

% Works
%\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone} 

\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 
\usepackage{animate} 

\begin{document} 

\begin{animateinline}[palindrome,controls]{12} 
\multiframe{10}{i=0+1}{% 
abc 
\begin{tikzpicture} % --> Removing the `tikzpicture` environment "removes" the error message.
\end{tikzpicture} 
} 
\end{animateinline} 

\end{document}
```

---

- I want to produce standalone diagrams, `pgfplots` package + `standalone` document class.
- I also want the diagrams to be animated, `animate` package.
- I get the error `! Missing \endgroup inserted.<inserted text>\endgroup\end{tikzpicture}}`.
- If I remove the `tikz` option from the document class then I do not get an error -- but if I have multiple diagrams then they are not on separate pages.
- I switched to `article` document class for now.

---

### Update

Inspired my AlexG's comment I tried this:

- Removing `tikz` option from document class.
- Inserting `\newpage` outside the `animateline` environments.
- But, same error.

> We can close the question -- I just wanted to make sure that it's not
>   a stupid mistake on my side :).

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone} 

%\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 
\usepackage{animate} 

\begin{document} 

\newpage
\begin{animateinline}[palindrome,controls]{12} 
\multiframe{10}{i=0+1}{% 
abc 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\end{tikzpicture} 
} 
\end{animateinline} 

\newpage
\begin{animateinline}[palindrome,controls]{12} 
\multiframe{10}{i=0+1}{% 
abc 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\end{tikzpicture} 
} 
\end{animateinline} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want an animated plot on a single standalone page, the `tikz` option doesn't make sense. It trims the papersize to the `tikzpicture` size and places `\newpage`s between the `tikzpicture`s, thus `\newpage`s inside an `animateinline` environment. This cannot compile without error.

Comment: On the other hand, if you want to produce a multipage document with standalone `tikzpictures` by means of the `tikz` option, the `animateinline` environment must be removed.

Comment: @AlexG Thanks. I thought it is a problem of the standalone class.

Comment: This isn't the first time the [tikz] option has caused problems.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277784/document-class-standalone-and-tikzfading-tikzfadingfrompicture

Comment: @AlexG I updated the question -- but we can end it here. Thanks for the time to look into it.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I see. Then I better not rely on it :). I have a work around (article mode and manual cropping or resizing the page with geometry) so it's ok for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is caused by placing `\newpage` in a `standalone` class document, as this simple, non-compiling example shows (everything removed from the OP's code except "abc" and `\newpage`):

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\newpage
abc

\newpage
abc

\end{document}
```

Instead, `\standaloneenv{...}` or `\begin{standalone}...\end{standalone}` should be used to tell which content should be typeset onto individual pages:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone} 

%\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 
\usepackage{animate} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\standaloneenv{animateinline}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document} 

\begin{animateinline}[palindrome,controls]{12} 
  \multiframe{10}{i=0+1}{% 
    \Huge\fbox{abc: \i}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \end{tikzpicture} 
  } 
\end{animateinline} 

\begin{animateinline}[palindrome,controls]{12} 
  \multiframe{10}{i=0+1}{% 
    \Huge\fbox{ijk: \i}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \end{tikzpicture} 
  } 
\end{animateinline} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works! Any reason you commented `%\usepackage{tikz}` out?

Comment: It was you ;), 2nd code box in the question.

Comment: Haha. No further questions my honor...

Comment: BTW, placing "abc" into a `standalone` environment still produces the reported error. This is in fact a bug of the class.