\usetikzlibrary{calc} doesn't work correctly in standalone documents
I have following problem: In my LaTeX project I have two standalone tikz documents in separate .tex files that plot some graphics. They both use calc for coordinates. They both individually compile without any issues. However when I compile my entire project, which imports the two tikz figures, I get the error "Package tikz Error: You need to say \usetikzlibrary{calc} for coordinate calculation."
I have by now figured out that the error arises from the compiler thinking it doesn't have to load calc again as it already has so before but tikz disagreeing as it requires it to be loaded separately in each document? Or something along those lines.
I have also found this supposed solution but can't get it to work at all. Adding the patch within each of my standalone files doesn't work, neither does adding it into my style.tex (where \makeatletter and \makeatother are called).
I'm no LaTeX expert by any means, so apologies if this is super trivial.
Any help is appreciated!

Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

The easy solution is to not use the [tikz] option, but use \usepackage{tikz} instead.  The reason is that [tikz] alwo provides [multi=tikzpicture], which will ignore anything outside a tikzpicture, including \usetikzlibrary{calc}.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277784/document-class-standalone-and-tikzfading-tikzfadingfrompicture/277790?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C18.1553#277790

@JohnKormylo that's not the problem here as the documents compile fine on their own.

My Crystal Ball (v.3.9 alpha pre-release) tells me you have something like this set up for your main document
\documentclass{book}
...
\usepackage{tikz}
...
\begin{document}
...
\input{tikzcode1}% or \includestandalone
...
\includestandalone{tikzcode2}% or \input
...
\end{document}

where each of tikzcode1.tex and tikzcode2.tex looks something like the following,
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
...
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Assuming the tikzpicture code is valid, this would result in the symptoms described: the pictures would compile fine on their own, but give the error you report when you try to compile the main document.
This happens because, by default, the preambles of the documents you pull into the main document are not read. Everything between \documentclass{standalone} and \begin{document} is skipped and \begin{document} ... \end{document} is redefined to roughly \begingroup ... \endgroup.
So you need to do something to tell the compiler to load the calc library in the preamble of your main document. (You do not want to localise this loading unless you have very special requirements and really know what you're doing. Libraries are designed to be loaded in the preamble.)
At least two options:

Add
 \usetikzlibrary{calc}

to the preamble of your main document.

Alternatively, use
 \usepackage[subpreambles]{standalone}

rather than
 \usepackage{standalone}

in the preamble of your main document. In that case, standalone will read and combine the preambles of the documents you pull in, but you will need an additional compilation cycle.



Your crystal ball is spot on! I should have been a little more explicit, my bad.
What you're saying makes sense but I did try to add to my main documents preamble without success before posting. But now that I better understand the problem I'll try again later and then update you here. Thank you!

Your first suggestion worked perfectly. For some reason the figures don't render exactly the same as when rendering them separately but I can work with that. I've accepted your answer.

@Klaus difference in fonts or font size? you don't say what's different...

yeah that is probably it! But it didn't matter, I just adjusted them to look good in the final document.
